# visual studio code starts showing printing options

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Why visual studio code starts showing printing options after selecting open with live server option?

[print options image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v02e5.png)

Comment: I'm guessing you have `print()` somewhere in your code.

Comment: ahh, ok i found it thank you!